# Programmatically refreshing a scope in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is there a way to programmatically refresh a scope in Rails?

I'm currently using scopes as below:

`scope :orphaned, lambda{where(prospects_count: 0)}`

I'd like the scope to be cached, but programmatically force a refresh any time records are added or deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Am not sure is there any options for forcing the scoped to execute. if you need this kind of feature create a method like

```
def orphaned
 orphaned = orphaned || self.where(:prospects_count => 0))
end
```

I think this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload